# disable frames in html

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

i have a page where i populate a popup screen, the page consists of some frames when i click on a link which has to populate a popup window it populates the window correctly but the html page alone get the background in block and the frames don't get the backround block.

Please see the image for reference, i will also past the files i use for that :

[image]

```
POPUP.JS

//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    $("#button").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});

and POPUP.CSS
#backgroundPopup{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000;
border:1px solid #cecece;
z-index:1;
}
#popupContact{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:384px;
width:750px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:2px solid #cecece;
z-index:2;
padding:12px;
font-size:13px;
overflow:scroll;
}
#popupContact h1{
text-align:left;
color:#333;
font-size:20px;
border-bottom:1px dotted #D3D3D3;
padding-bottom:5px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#popupContactClose{
font-size:14px;
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
color:#6fa5fd;
font-weight:700;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
#button{
text-align:center;
}

and the html : 

<div id="popupContact">
    <a id="popupContactClose"><img src="images/x.png" alt="X" /></a>
    <h1>Reports</h1>
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header">Sl. No</th>
                <th class="header">Checkbox</th>
                <th class="header">Size</th>
                <th class="header">Display</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>4</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>6</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>8</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>10</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>12</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>        
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

Please help me how to go about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and it seems from the image that the popup is centered to your middle frame.. so actually you did not get the main window's height and width to position your popup. Also the opacity you applied.. that div is not covering the whole window.. its limited to your current frame I guess..

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a good way to do this in a frameset (which is [obsolete in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)). A window may not place their own elements on top of other windows<sup>1</sup>.

A hack way of accomplishing this would be to let all `frames` in the `frameset` know that you want modal behavior, and have them each display a blocking element (as you are doing in the main frame). This would probably happen from your `loadPopup()` method.

A regular popup window is probably a cleaner alternative.

But really, there is no good reason to use a frameset, especially for the layout pictured.

<sup>1 - As a point of historical trivia, IE once allowed a special type of element overlay which could cover other windows/frames. This was shown to be a particular bad idea when hackers used it to generate an element which covered the address bar of the browser with a fake URL.</sup>

Comment: hi @ZippyV thanks for the comment, if this is the case shall go with normal HTML design? where can i get help to design the same also if you see the left side menu, it will go in if i click and expand if i click again, i want to the same, how to do this?